# Can't reach ressources of my phone through APK using phonegap build

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, apk, device

I'm working on an app with PhoneGap/Cordova who use the camera of my device and show me his properties.

I created an app with line command "phonegap create ...." then add camera and device plugin using these line

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

then I edited my index.html to use camera and show the properties.

Get the properties.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                window.document.getElementById("version").innerHTML=device.version;
                window.document.getElementById("uuid").innerHTML=device.uuid;
                window.document.getElementById("modele").innerHTML=device.model;
                window.document.getElementById("platform").innerHTML=device.platform;
                console.log(device.model);}
```

a part of html

```
<div data-role="page" id="property">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>En-tête</h1>
  </div>
   <div data-role="content">
  <div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>Propriétét du téléphone</h3>
      <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Modèle</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="modele">Attendez</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

And camera.

```
        function capturePhoto(){
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,null,{sourceType:1,quality:60});
    }
    function uploadPhoto(data){
    // this is where you would send the image file to server
        cameraPic.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
        // Successful upload to the server
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Votre photo à été envoyée',  // message
            okay,                           // callback
            'Photo envoyée',              // title
            'OK'                          // buttonName
        );
```

Html

```
<div data-role="page" id="camera">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Camera</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="camera">
            <button class="camera-control" onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>
            <div style="text-align:center;margin:20px;">
                <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:auto;height:120px;"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#default" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left">Retour</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

My code is working on the live application "PhoneGap Developper" i can take a picture and see the spec of my phone.

```
cd myApp
phonegap serve listening on 127.0.0.1
```

but when i create an APK with PhoneGap Build(upload my zip file and build it), the camera doesn't work and it seems like i can't reach the ressources of my smartphone.

PS : when i create an APK my app is tiny, like if it was coded for computer screen but appear normal on phonegap live app.

PS.2 : when i want to add a platform to my phonegap project, he need a path but I don't know where to find the file or the path.

I'm using

- Cordova 4.1.2
- Phonegap 4.1.2-0.22.9
- LG G3 with Android 4.4.2

Thanks for reading me, hope I'm clear and specific

English is not my native language so, i apologize if there's some error

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems :

1. as you created the project using cordova cli and not phonegap, the config.xml probably hasn't the right dtd to be compatible with phonegap build specific syntax
2. You have to declare plugins in config.xml to be able to use it with phonegap build.

So in your config.xml, use

```
<widget id="com.test.yourapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

instead of

```
<widget id="com.test.yourapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

And add lines to add the plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
```

Next time start by reading the docs of the service ;) : https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1173

Comment: <widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

This was already on my .xml and plugin line is already added on my .xml when i add them with the command line.

Comment: you say the plugin lines are added when you use the cordova cli with commands you provided in your question (not phonegap)? In that case many things changed in version 4!

Comment: So if your plugin is supposed to be added and not working, did you try to get logs to check if there are errors (either using weinre or logcat)

Comment: 1. Yep they're add when i use the command line, btw i use command that the doc of phonegap give me, so i think yes the v.4 does that.

2. No i dont, i'm new in this univers of mobile app :D i'll do this and give you news :D

3. Thanks for u help